# Multiple output based web api action returning result under item1, item2... instead of named property

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, tuples

I have a dot net core web api action which return two values. Since my action is async so i can return result like this :

**async Task<(int rollno, string email)> MyAction();**

But when I am looking at http response I am geeing result under node **item1, item2.**

I want to return data with the node rollno and email instead of **Item1 and Item2.**

I used Tuple also but nothing working as expected.

Comment: The easiest solution is to use an object with those two properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're return is a `ValueTuple`, which is just a special kind of `Tuple` that enables the compiler to interpret things like `rollno` and `email` as equivalent to `Item1`, `Item2`, etc. on a `Tuple`. However, when you serialize this (which is what happens when you return it from an action), it's going to serialize as a `Tuple`, because that's what it really is under the hood, resulting in `Item1` and `Item2` coming out of the wash.

Long and short, you should not return tuples, `ValueTuple` or not, from action methods. Create a class to represent what you're returning, and then return an instance of that class.